# Disable pan and zoom on Windows Mobile Explorer 6

Tags: windows-mobile, activex

I have a web page that is used with mobile devices to take signatures, but the signature component doesn't work well in windows mobile 6. 
When moving the stylus across the component, the screen will pan.

I have reduced the viewport size using

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">

but even though this stops the screen panning, the signature still does not work correctly. 
I assume that the stylus movements are still being captured for panning and zooming & are not being sent to the activex component.

Is there any way to turn off the panning so that mouse movements are correctly sent to the active-x component?

A test signature screen can be seen here...
http://prague.dynamicselect.co.uk/cctest_engweb/sigtest.asp

Comment: connection to http://prague.dynamicselect.co.uk/cctest_engweb/sigtest.asp timed out

Comment: try it again. not sure why it timed out, but it's fine for me.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can control that option, the same way you can't control page orientation when printing in a normal web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [TKSetWindowAutoGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220919.aspx) function and the corresponding [WAGINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220941.aspx) structure which allows you to specify the gesture-handling functionality for a given window handle. You would have to do this from the ActiveX control, not in the HTML obviously.

I don't have a working example as I am not a Windows Mobile developer, but we had a very similar situation with the Tablet PC when trying to accept ink input in an area that was being served by Vista flick gestures.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, you can disable the zoom feature by adding registry values in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft.

Add key Internet Explorer with subkey Zoom. 
Add a DWORD (32-bit) to the subkey called ZoomDisabled and a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

you can change registry value:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\
OverviewZoomLandscape or OverviewZoomPortrait change the values as you want [screen size].

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on iPhone and Android but unfortunately not the custom HTC android browser. 
Haven't tested on windows mobile.

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to Microsoft, you can disable the zoom feature by adding
>   registry values in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft.
>
> Add key Internet Explorer with subkey Zoom. Add a DWORD (32-bit) to
>   the subkey called ZoomDisabled and a value of 1.

Tested on CE 07.00.2806 - not works! And in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software no such a key Policies so we need begin create keys from Policies and so on...

Comment: After this key - no panning auto zoom works in ie on wince 7: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\EditActivation]
"EnableEditActivation"=dword:0